# Ready to use objects instead of 3D-printing them

Tags: 3d-design, cnc

I hope this kind of questions are tolerated here. Otherwise, please tell me in the comment and I will delete the question - no needs to downvote.

---

For a new job I need to create a lot of objects like this one:

[image]

To have an idea of the dimensions:

- height: 60 mm
- cylinder diameter: 12 mm
- inner hole: 3 mm
- lateral slots width (2 at 90 degress): 3 mm

I'm able to make such an item with either a 3D printer or even a standard 4-axis CNC.
But because I need to make 100+ of these items I wonder if there are something similar out there.

But I have no idea of how it might be called. I tried with "spacer with slots" without any useful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your printer is reliable enough I would suggest printing multiple parts in one go. Since the cylinders are only 12 mm in diameter you can easily fit over a hundred of them on a standard 20 x 20 cm built plate with a couple of millimeters spacing in between.

Comment: You _could_ fit that many. My experience is it makes individual layer times too long, creating problems with warping, especially in the early layers. I'd go for lots of 20 or so.